# SQL query to link two tables returning error

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows

user [ ID , username ]

relationship [ user1_id(FK) , user2_id (FK) , status ]

I am trying to get the `username` by using either `user1_id` or `user2_id` where the `status = 1` from `relationship` table. `user1_id` and `user2_id` are both `ID`s from the `user` table. The following query is failing and I am not sure where it's going wrong.

```
SELECT
  U.username,
  (R.first_user_id, R.second_user_id AS friends)
FROM
  user U,
  `relationship` R
WHERE (R.`first_user_id` = {$userID} OR R.`second_user_id`)
  AND (`status` = 1 AND U.ID = friends)
```

Comment: Show some sample data and expected results.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: From the title: `query returning error`. Where is this error? Add it to the question.

Comment: at least `friends` is not available in the `WHERE` statement `U.ID = friends`

Comment: Maybe it's a Mysql thing I don't know about, but what's supposed to be the meaning of the parentheses around the second and third items in the selection list?

Comment: The `OR R.\`second_user_id\`` seems to be missing a relational operator and comparison value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returns both names of users in a relationship with a status of 1.
this also assumes that if a relationship record exists, both users must be in the user table.

```
SELECT U1.UserName, U2.username
FROM Relationship R
INNER JOIN USER U1
 on R.User1_ID = U1.user_ID
INNER JOIN USER U2
 and R.User2_ID = U2.user_ID
WHERE R.Status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be trying to get the usernames of all users that have a relationship with a certain specified user, regardless of the order of user IDs in the relationship record.  That could be this:

```
SELECT
  U.username,
  U.first_user_id,
FROM
  user U
  JOIN `relationship` R
    ON R.first_user_id = U.ID
WHERE
  (R.`second_user_id` = {$userID})
    AND (`status` = 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  U.username,
  U.second_user_id,
FROM
  user U
  JOIN `relationship` R
    ON R.second_user_id = U.ID
WHERE
  (R.`first_user_id` = {$userID})
    AND (`status` = 1)
```

If that produces duplicates (or could do) and you don't want it to do, then change the `UNION ALL` to a straight `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded based on xQbert answer:

```
                  SELECT 
                        U1.username, 
                        U2.username
                    AS user_friend
                    FROM 
                        Relationship R
                    INNER JOIN 
                        user U1
                     ON 
                        R.first_user_id = U1.ID
                    INNER JOIN 
                        user U2
                     ON 
                        R.second_user_id = U2.ID
                    WHERE (R.`first_user_id` = {$userID} OR R.`second_user_id` = {$userID})
                    AND `status` = 1
```